# Parse HTML and preserve original content

Tags: python, html, ruby, node.js, html-parsing

I have lots of HTML files. I want to replace some elements, keeping all the other content unchanged. For example, I would like to execute this jQuery expression (or some equivalent of it):

```
$('.header .title').text('my new content')
```

on the following HTML document:

```
<div class=header><span class=title>Foo</span></div>
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
```

and have the following result:

```
<div class=header><span class=title>my new content</span></div>
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
```

The problem is, all parsers I’ve tried ([Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [html5lib](https://code.google.com/p/html5lib)) serialize it to something like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class=header><span class=title>my new content</span></div>
    <p>1</p><p>2</p>
    <table><tbody><tr><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

E.g. they add:

1. html, head and body elements
2. closing p tags
3. tbody

Is there a parser that satisfies my needs? It should work in either Node.js, Ruby or Python.

Comment: pyparsing of python may help. It's great with supporting HTML tags and doesn't add missing tags. Look at makeXMLTags function.

Comment: to help improve the answers you might indicate what you don't like about lxml.html based solutions e.g.,  [@bukzor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11583283/4279)

Comment: It closes `<p>` tags and adds quotes to attributes.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but _why_ don't you want the HTML to be fixed? (close `<p>`s etc) - it's not like it's going to break things - likely just the opposite.

Comment: It’s not broken, It’s perfectly valid HTML. I’m writing a migration script which replaces some HTML in templates. I don’t to do any side-effect changes.

Comment: Are your use cases actually complicated enough or could you do with a RegExp? Sometimes it's just easier to make your own solution then trying to search for a library that does precisely what you want.

Comment: I think the provided example is already complicated enough for a RegExp.

Answer (score 11):

I highly recommend the [pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/) package, for python. It is a jquery-like interface layered ontop of the extremely reliable [lxml](http://lxml.de/) package, a python binding to libxml2.

I believe this does exactly what you want, with a quite familiar interface.

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
html = '''
<div class=header><span class=title>Foo</span></div>
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
'''
doc = pq(html)

doc('.header .title').text('my new content')
print doc
```

Output:

```
<div><div class="header"><span class="title">my new content</span></div>
<p>1</p><p>2
</p><table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table></div>
```

The closing p tag can't be helped. `lxml` only keeps the *values* from the original document, not the vagaries of the original. Paragraphs can be made two ways, and it chooses the more standard way when doing serialization. I don't believe you'll find a (bug-free) parser that does better.

Comment: really didn't thought people will this kind of thing, it is really neat.

Comment: @zinking sounds like you accidentally a whole verb in that sentence.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** I'm on Python 3.

This will only handle a subset of CSS selectors, but it may be enough for your purposes.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class AttrQuery():
    def __init__(self):
        self.repl_text = ""
        self.selectors = []

    def add_css_sel(self, seltext):
        sels = seltext.split(" ")

        for selector in sels:
            if selector[:1] == "#":
                self.add_selector({"id": selector[1:]})
            elif selector[:1] == ".":
                self.add_selector({"class": selector[1:]})
            elif "." in selector:
                html_tag, html_class = selector.split(".")
                self.add_selector({"html_tag": html_tag, "class": html_class})
            else:
                self.add_selector({"html_tag": selector})

    def add_selector(self, selector_dict):
        self.selectors.append(selector_dict)

    def match_test(self, tagwithattrs_list):
        for selector in self.selectors:
            for condition in selector:
                condition_value = selector[condition]
                if not self._condition_test(tagwithattrs_list, condition, condition_value):
                    return False
        return True

    def _condition_test(self, tagwithattrs_list, condition, condition_value):
        for tagwithattrs in tagwithattrs_list:
            try:
                if condition_value == tagwithattrs[condition]:
                    return True
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return False


class HTMLAttrParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, html, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.tagwithattrs_list = []
        self.queries = []
        self.matchrepl_list = []
        self.html = html

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        tagwithattrs = dict(attrs)
        tagwithattrs["html_tag"] = tag
        self.tagwithattrs_list.append(tagwithattrs)

        if debug:
            print("push\t", end="")
            for attrname in tagwithattrs:
                print("{}:{}, ".format(attrname, tagwithattrs[attrname]), end="")
            print("")

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        try:
            while True:
                tagwithattrs = self.tagwithattrs_list.pop()
                if debug:
                    print("pop \t", end="")
                    for attrname in tagwithattrs:
                        print("{}:{}, ".format(attrname, tagwithattrs[attrname]), end="")
                    print("")
                if tag == tagwithattrs["html_tag"]: break
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("Found a close-tag for a non-existent element.")

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.tagwithattrs_list:
            for query in self.queries:
                if query.match_test(self.tagwithattrs_list):
                    line, position = self.getpos()
                    length = len(data)
                    match_replace = (line-1, position, length, query.repl_text)
                    self.matchrepl_list.append(match_replace)

    def addquery(self, query):
        self.queries.append(query)

    def transform(self):
        split_html = self.html.split("\n")
        self.matchrepl_list.reverse()
        if debug: print ("\nreversed list of matches (line, position, len, repl_text):\n{}\n".format(self.matchrepl_list))

        for line, position, length, repl_text in self.matchrepl_list:
            oldline = split_html[line]
            newline = oldline[:position] + repl_text + oldline[position+length:]
            split_html = split_html[:line] + [newline] + split_html[line+1:]

        return "\n".join(split_html)
```

See the example usage below.

```
html_test = """<div class=header><span class=title>Foo</span></div>
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td class=hi><div id=there>1</div></td></tr></table>"""

debug = False
parser = HTMLAttrParser(html_test)

query = AttrQuery()
query.repl_text = "Bar"
query.add_selector({"html_tag": "div", "class": "header"})
query.add_selector({"class": "title"})
parser.addquery(query)

query = AttrQuery()
query.repl_text = "InTable"
query.add_css_sel("table tr td.hi #there")
parser.addquery(query)

parser.feed(html_test)

transformed_html = parser.transform()
print("transformed html:\n{}".format(transformed_html))
```

Output:

```
transformed html:
<div class=header><span class=title>Bar</span></div>
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td class=hi><div id=there>InTable</div></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: The best answer so far. Still, 1) I want to search using any CSS selector. I don’t want to roll out my own CSS selector engine. 2) I want to parse HTML once and then do *several* transformations. Re-parsing HTML before every transformation isn’t the most performant way to do it.

Comment: Made one more update.  While this won't support the full spectrum of CSS selectors, it would allow you to select by tag, class, and id.  It could be extended to support other selectors, such as "p + table", but others would be more difficult.  I looked and there doesn't seem a straight-forward way to combine the best of the @bukzor's solution and mine.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I have done this in a few languages and I have to say the best parser I have seen that preserves whitespace and even HTML comments is:

**[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)** which is unfortunately **Java**.

That is Jericho knows how to parse and preserve fragments.

Yes I know its Java but you could easily make a RESTful service with a tiny bit of Java that would take the payload and convert it. In the Java REST service you could use JRuby, Jython, Rhino Javascript etc. to coordinate with Jericho.

Comment: I'm sure I'm getting down voted by Java haters. Keep down voting me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nokogiri HTML Fragment for this:

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<div class=header><span class=title>Foo</span></div>
                                    <p>1<p>2
                                    <table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>')

fragment.css('.title').children.first.replace(Nokogiri::XML::Text.new('HEY', fragment))

frament.to_s #=> "<div class=\"header\"><span class=\"title\">HEY</span></div>\n<p>1</p><p>2\n</p><table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>"
```

The problem with the `p` tag persists, because it is invalid HTML, but this should return your document without html, head or body and tbody tags.

Comment: It's quite valid html. It's part of the html5 spec.

Comment: @bukzor and how do you deduce exactly that html5 or even html4 is used for the example in question? By [XHTML standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html) it is invalid to have non-empty paragraphs without closing tag, and I bet you won't find any good parser out there which does not implement XHTML, because without it, accurate tree structures of documents would be nearly impossible.

Comment: It's certainly html, and I've never seen anyone use html 3 :P xhtml is a dead standard. html5 has supplanted it.

Comment: @bukzor The final html5 spec comes out in 2014, support for it is growing, but not available everywhere. It will also contain XHTML5. Both are years away from official recommendation status. HTML 4 and XHTML are not dead just because we'd like to think they're dead. They remain the standard until they're officially replaced.

Comment: html5 supports both HTML and XML syntaxes. The end tag for `p` element may be omitted in some cases for HTML syntax.

Comment: __may__ doesn't mean neither __must__ nor __should__

Answer (score 1):

With **Python** - using `lxml.html` is fairly straight forward:
(It meets points 1 & 3, but I don't think much can be done about 2, and handles the unquoted `class=`'s)

```
import lxml.html

fragment = """<div class=header><span class=title>Foo</span></div>
<p>1<p>2
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
"""

page = lxml.html.fromstring(fragment)
for span in page.cssselect('.header .title'):
    span.text = 'my new value'
print lxml.html.tostring(page, pretty_print=True)
```

Result:

```
<div>
<div class="header"><span class="title">my new content</span></div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2
</p>
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: The goal is a high-fidelity parse/unparse roundtrip. Don't pretty print.

Comment: @bukzor Okay - how that the "goal" from the information in the post is a "high-fidelity parse/unparse roundtrip" is beyond me, but fine. This is an example, and the pprint is to make reading the results easier for us humans to compare input/output. If it is not needed, then fine, just don't use it -- it's simple to remove.

Comment: Reference: `I want to replace some elements, keeping all the other content unchanged.` I see the pretty print, but others less familiar with lxml may not. `, True` is not the most explicit thing ever.

Comment: @bukzor Okay. Have changed it to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly separate solution but if this is only for a few simple instances then perhaps CSS is the answer.

[Generated Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #header.title1:first-child:before {
      content: "This is your title!";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #header.title2:first-child:before {
      content: "This is your other title!";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="header" class="title1">
    <span class="non-title">Blah Blah Blah Blah</span>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this instance you could just have jQuery swap the classes and you'd get the change for free with css. I haven't tested this particular usage but it should work.

We use this for things like outage messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a Node.js app, this module will do exactly what you want, a JQuery style DOM manipulator: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

An example from their wiki:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
//=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```